# Struts2 dynamic action names

Tags: java, struts2

The problem is simple, I don't know if has a simple solution: I'm using JPA to persist images to a database. I'm also using Struts 2.

I wrote an action that take the image from the db and sand it to the client.

The problem is that in this way, when people try to download the image on their PC, they have to write a name for the file (default is something like image.action - always the same).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [Content-Disposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) HTTP Header to specify the filename of the resource.  For example:

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename: file.jpg
```

You can add this to your [`HttpServletResponse`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#setHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) like so:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename: file.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another simple way to do this, all you have to do is to setup **StreamResult** in ***strut.xml***

More detail, reference this [page](http://sheetalshundori.blogspot.com/2008/02/struts2-dynamic-file-download.html)